# Origins of "turn over in his grave"?; "turn over in her grave"? etc., etc

Tags: etymology, expressions, origin-unknown

The best result of my google-search for the origins of the idiomatic phrase, “**turn over in the grave**” was this, from wikipedia:

> One of the earliest uses is found in William Thackeray's 1849 work The
>   History of Pendennis, where Mrs. Wapshot, upset by a man's advances on
>   the widow of Mr. Pendennis whom the widow had "never liked," says it's
>   "enough to make poor Mr. Pendennis turn in his grave."

**Can anyone out there trace the phrase back further than 1849?**

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that it somehow relates to witchcraft traditions in England.

Comment: I am sure this exists in other languages as well.

Comment: This is a good question for the American Dialect Society Listserv (ADS-L). Submit what was supplied here, and see if they can "antedate" it.

Comment: A little off-topic, but _very important_: "Roll Over Beethoven" was written by Chuck Berry. (So if "roll over" really is a variant, it's from Missouri.)

Comment: _But first I'll turn yon fellow in his grave;_ Shakespeare, Richard III (c1592) but I don't think it means the same thing; I think it means _put / roll / dump/ turf_ http://shakespeare.mit.edu/richardiii/full.html

Comment: Listserv is a type of mailing list, i.e. you send an email to the listserv and it redistributes it to everyone who is a subscriber.  More information about this particular one seems to be available from http://www.americandialect.org/publications/ads-l-the-american-dialect-society-email-discussion-list

Comment: +1 Thank you @tripleee, nobody tells me anything around here!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I can try to set it back much further.

The [Gemara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemara) are old Jewish texts. I can not say how old, as today is the first time I heard about them, but surely from before 1842, Wikipedia gives a date of 500 CE.

In there, in [Sotah 7b](http://halakhah.com/sotah/sotah_7.html#7b), it says ([in the English translation by Soncino](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Sotah&df=7b)):

> All the years that the Israelites were in the wilderness, Judah's
>   bones kept turning in his coffin until Moses arose and begged mercy
>   for him.

The [original](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=7b&format=pdf) reads:

> כל אותן שנים שהיו ישראל במדבר היו עצמותיו של יהודה מגולגלין בארון עד
>   שעמד משה ובקש עליו רחמים

I don't know if the 'modern' usage goes back to this text, it might have been 'reinvented' in the 1800s.

Comment: 500 CE sounds about right. And yes, Sotah 7b is the proper way to refer to pages.

Comment: Please don't take me as a killjoy: How "literally" is this translated? A translation might use a figure of speech from "modern English" to express a different Hebrew phrase with similar meaning...

Comment: @Stephie Extremely literally. The Hebrew is "היו עצמותיו של יהודה מגולגלין בארון" -- Judah's bones would turn in the coffin.

Comment: Stephie: I had not thought of the possibility that the translator could have inserted the figure of speech, so you were right to mention that possibility. Scimonster has answered your question by giving the original text. I tried to edit my answer and copy Scimonster's text in, but when I copy the Hebrew in, but all I get are question marks...

Comment: + 99 (would that I could), You've done such great detective work @Phil. I hate to deflate, but I'm not sure the sense of 'Judah's bones turning in his coffin' (**like tumbling dice**) is the same as a whole 'corpse turning over in its grave.' (**Going from face up to face down**, that's significant symbolism). Apparently, Judah and his dead kin, being carted around the wilderness for generations, were reduced to loose, clattering bones. Then, too, there is that bit about the bones reattaching themselves. I need more input. **Can any of ya'll reading this help to clarify these questions?**

Comment: I edited for clarity and sense, Pieter - intending no disrespect. "immediately [after Moses prayed], 'Hear, Lord, the voice of Judah', each limb [Of the skeleton] entered its socket [and ceased rolling about]."

Comment: Pakk, the translation is valid and the Rabbi's comments don't intrude on what's pertinent, so it comes down to the sense, and that I'm not qualified to judge without help from the scholars.

Comment: @LittleEva The sense of "גלגול" (the word used here for rolling) is used for turning over -- a wheel is a "גלגל החוזר." Jastrow (a dictionary of Talmudic Hebrew/Aramaic) [renders](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EeO2l.png) the word as "roll," among other definitions.

Comment: @LittleEva The passage is explaining that he was "tossing in his grave" over distress, that he wasn't being allowed into Heaven. He had promised his father Jacob to bring back Benjamin, and if not, would "sin for all eternity" (i.e. not enter Heaven). Due to the technicality of him bringing Jacob to Egypt instead of the family back to Canaan, he never fulfilled his promise. That is why he was distressed, and "turning in his grave". When Moses prayed, God let Judah into Heaven.

Comment: +1 @Scimonster - so you feel it carries the same or similar sense as the more modern idiomatic usage?

Comment: @LittleEva Yes, that's what it seems to me.

Comment: @Shokhet - and you? This is important stuff, we've entered the 'sacred' now ... don't want to get this wrong.

Comment: Yes, @LittleEva, I think that it's the same idea in both idioms.

Comment: My thoughts are that I am not qualified to judge on how to interpret old Hebrew texts. I thought the question was interesting, and suspected a religious origin, and my search engine skills led me to this answer. I trust the two opinions before that this is the same idiom as is currently used, but with my limited knowledge on this I can not give you more.

Comment: @Shoket & Scimonster - Sotah 7b may be from 500 CE, but the references cited in footnotes are to scriptures from Gen. XXXVIII, 26 and Deut. XXXIII, 6f. These greatly antedate 500 CE, correct?

Comment: @LittleEva: Yes, but I don't think that these have the meaning that this gemara talks about, without the interpretation of the gemara. The cited verses say "צדקה ממני," "she is more righteous than I;" and "וזאת ליהודה" "and this is for Judah" ....there isn't much there in the way of "turning over in the grave."

Comment: The Gemara is a synonym for the Talmud. There are two variants - the Jerusalemite and the Babylonian (Yerushalmi and Bavli) - created by the two larger agglomeration of Jewish scholars at those times. "Those times" are after the earlier religious text (and codex) called the Mishna was finalized. So, Mishna at around 200 CE, Talmud is accumulated over the next several centuries or so, then Talmud is finalized between/around 500-600 CE.

Comment: I don't know why everybody is talking about Hebrew, given that the Talmud isn't written in Hebrew, it's written in Aramaic @Scimonster

Comment: @barlop It's written mostly in Aramaic, yes, but also has Hebrew sections. This is one of them.

Comment: I would note re margana's edit, that both those links are the soncino translation, the one that was there and the one you added.  The one with all english is how soncino present it, the other one added in the edit has the hebrew thrown to the side not very parallel, though good that it has the hebrew

Answer (score 13):

I can push it back a little further, but not much. Here's what Google Books gives for 1700–1849:

> [1848](https://books.google.com/books?id=vEg2AQAAMAAJ&q=%22turn+in+his+grave%22&dq=%22turn+in+his+grave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OSHYVLWRII3nsAT99YGgDg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBw) – Why, his very bones would turn in his grave at the bare thought of it — *Farmers' Library and Monthly Journal of Agriculture*, Volume 3
>
> [1847](https://books.google.com/books?id=vEg2AQAAMAAJ&q=%22turn+in+his+grave%22&dq=%22turn+in+his+grave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OSHYVLWRII3nsAT99YGgDg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBw) – Could our deceased father hear that, I think he’d turn in his grave. — *Rambleton: A Romance of Fashionable Life in New-York During the Great Speculation of 1836*
>
> [1845](https://books.google.com/books?id=ULFZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA203&dq=%22turn+in+his+grave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OSHYVLWRII3nsAT99YGgDg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ) – The Scotch Presbyterians are building a stone Gothic temple in Oxford-road, which would almost make John Knox turn in his grave with dismay. — *The Foreign Quarterly Review*, Vol 35
>
> [1843](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ev0EAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA236&dq=%22turn+in+his+grave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OSHYVLWRII3nsAT99YGgDg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22turn%20in%20his%20grave%22&f=false) –What has become of Prussian honour? A general of infantry, with fourteen battalions and twenty escadrons, runs away before 2500 men! If your father could hear this it would make him turn in his grave. —  *The Foreign Quarterly Review*
>
> [1842](https://books.google.com/books?id=fNoEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA385&dq=%22turn+in+his+grave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OSHYVLWRII3nsAT99YGgDg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg) – Burke may smile, or turn in his grave, if he pleases ; yet the assertion just made is true.  — *The Eclectic Review*, Vol 1

Thackeray seems to have had a pretty live ear for currently fashionable language.

Comment: +1 That's good, @Stoney (the TV said *Stony* Lewis just as I was trying to type your name - uncanny!), I should have found that. Thanks.

Comment: @LittleEva Google Books is a great resource for this sort of thing, but you have to be very careful with the reported results: there are a **lot** of errors in their database, so you have to pretty much check the dates on every hit.

Answer (score 13):

The oldest reference I've found in English uses the phrase **turn in his coffin**, used with the same meaning as that required.  It comes from **1802**, in **[The Anti-Jacobin Review and Magazine](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=swc2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22could%20he%20be%20sensible%20to%20a%20twentieth%20part%22&source=bl&ots=_XKJ0qrwwu&sig=CJKtmDMRMS4M99Wdhe8vNx5s48Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XMDYVKioO4bUavqSgAg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22could%20he%20be%20sensible%20to%20a%20twentieth%20part%22&f=false)** (page 28) in the following passage:

> I should be glad to know what our ancestors would have thought and felt in this situation? what those weak a deluded men, so inferior to the politicians of the present day, the Marlboroughs, the Godolphins, the Somers's (sp?), the King Williams, all those who view with such apprehension the power of Louis XIV., what they would say to a peace, which not only confirms to France the possession of nearly the whole of Europe, but extends her empire over every other part of the globe.  Is there a man of them, who would not **turn in his coffin** could he be sensible to a twentieth part of that which is passing, as perfect matter of course, in the politicks of the present moment?

**[Falkner; a novel](https://archive.org/details/falknernovel13shel)** the final novel by Mary Shelley, written in **1837** includes this sentence (pp 27 to 28):

> It was bad enough now, 
>   but, by and by, she saw nothing but the 
>   parish ; though Missy was born for better than 
>   that, and her poor mamma would **turn in her 
>   grave** at the name of such a thing.

On **October 26 1816** in **[Cobbett's Weekly Political Pamphlet](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000116572482;view=1up;seq=211)** (page 409) is the sentence:

> These regulations , and the penalties which are attached to any breach of them, operate to an almost total exclusion of the common people from any considerable portion of useful knowledge through the means of the press, about the *freedom* of which our unprincipled hirelings have still the audacity to boast, though if our forefathers could hear of the state of slavery to which it is reduced, the hearing of it would make them **turn in their graves**.

Not quite so early, but still significant in terms of the adoption of the phrase, is that it was used in the UK parliament on **April 19 1831**, as recorded by **[Hansard](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b5481552;view=1up;seq=823)** (p1609)

> A predecessor of the right hon. Gentleman in the Chair had declared, that practices were now openly avowed with respect to seats in that House, which were sufficient to make our ancestors, could they be informed of them, turn in their graves;

Comment: @LittleEva gone another 21 yrs further back now

Comment: found "turn in their graves" via google books, then googled the name of the publication and found that hathitrust listed it too.

Comment: @LittleEva Yes, I am.  Personally I doubt that the phrase has leapt 1300 years form Hebrew to English with nothing in between.  I'm currently trying to find if it occurs in Latin or Greek. Meanwhile, I've pushed the date back to 1802.

Comment: Herodotus (5th century BC) uses "Agamemnon would wail loudly" to mean the same thing.  It is in fact sometimes translated as "Agamemnon would turn in his grave", but not literally, alas.

Comment: Yes, Phil, I do believe you're correct, it's used in the same sense. So close!

Answer (score 4):

"sich im Grab umdrehen" is a common saying in German. I did not research but my guess is that the saying wandered from German into English, perhaps by translation of novels. But maybe already the old Romans had this saying.

Added: There is not much to be found about the German saying. There are instances from the 18th c. (Lessing, Gellert) and it is assumed that the saying is older. I skimmed through Grimm's article Grab (grave) and found nothing about the saying, even though the article Grab is a book. - Added: Grimm has two instances for the saying  under umdrehen, from about 1800-1830.

The saying is found in other languages too.

Spanish: revolcarse en la tumba.

Italian: rivoltarsi nella tomba.

Comment: Yeah, rogermue, that's exactly what's behind my query. It's kind of hard to believe it only dates to 1842 (thanks, Stoney) or is exclusive to the English language cultures. The voice of Tradition admonishing the folly of Youth. It must connect to ancestor worship where it was a violation of taboo to even propose innovation. Irritating deceased ancestors was--still is--a universal fear (and threat) of Anthropos.

Comment: I had a look at the data base DWDS but they have no info about the saying. But I'll have a look at Grimm DWB. But Grimm can't have info about the wandering of the saying into English.

Comment: This is turning out to be virtually universal an timeless, going back into the dim mist. Thanks for the input. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Answer (score 2):

None of the references I checked gave an earlier first-occurrence date than Wikipedia's, but one—*The Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms* (1998)—makes the interesting claim that, while the phrase "turn in [one's] grave" is "British, American & Australian," the allied phrases "turn over in [one's] grave" and "spin in [one's] grave" are strictly American. Evidently, disgruntled corpses tend to be livelier in the United States than in the rest of the world. The earliest deceased spinners in a Google Books search [date only to 1902](https://books.google.com/books?id=PDNaAAAAYAAJ&q=%22spin+in+his+grave%22&dq=%22spin+in+his+grave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=s1PYVPq9E4HUoASk2YGQDg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAzgK), however.

Comment: Beethoven was a "spinner"! And he's Germanic!

Comment: People were buried face down as a sign of shame or disrespect. The significance of the saying is that they turn once to end up face down because you have disgraced them, spinning or turning multiple times is just misspeak.

Comment: Yes, +1 @James Ryan, that's right.

Comment: I think "spin" is simply hyperbole applied to "roll over".  The kind of thing one would expect in The Machine Age where everything is faster.